# Question on Value Type: Integer and Structures

Tags: .net, vb.net

**Question 1:**
Suppose I write `Dim x as Integer = 10`. Then this creates a space in the stack memory where 10 is stored. Given that value types return a copy when accessed, when we write `x = x + 1`, does it mean that a new space on the stack memory will be allocated and 11 stored in it (with the previously allocated memory space remaining as it is)? Or will 10 get updated to 11 in the previous memory space?

The reason for asking this question is to understand what it means to access a value type data. I explain my point in detail below.

I read that "When value types are **accessed**, they return a copy". But what is meant by "**accessing a value type**" is not clear to me. Let me explain. For example as it has been pointed out by @jimi in one of the comments, if I assign a variable to another variable ;i.e. dim a = 10 and then b = a, then a copy of a is made in b. A new memory space is created. Similarly when I pass a value type in a procedure as argument a copy of it s passed. Till this point, things are clear. However I a unable to extend the idea of "**accessing**" value types when I try to understand the explain why a FORM class instance is unable to set the the height/width of the SIZE property directly. That is, we cannot write:

```
Dim f As New MyForm()
f.size.height = 15   'Doesn't Work
f.size.height = 25   'Doesn't work
```

One explanation that I found ([Explanation Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)) is that when the compiler resolves `f.size.height` then, it first evaluates `f.size` which RETURNS a value type data (SIZE property is of structure type) and **therefore actually returns a copy**. Therefore we are actually setting the size of a copy of the form through the form which the compiler disallows.

What confuses me in the above explanation is how to understand what circumstances do we get a copy of a value type back? For example as mentioned before when we assign a variable to another variable, or when we pass a value type data as a parameter of a procedure we are dealing with a copy of the value type. But in the first example mentioned in the question, as clarified by @jimi in one of the comments, we are not creating a copy - value of x gets updated in the same memory location. This means that when we write x = x+ 1 we are not "accessing" the value of x. So then the question is how to define "accessing a value type data"? And if that definition can be used to explain why we cant write `f.size.height = 15`?

Comment: *"Question 2"*. No. That's not how it works. SO requires that you ask one question at a time. Including multiple questions in one post is one of the reasons provided for closing a question, which this one should be if it is not edited. You should edit this question and remove the second part, posting it as a separate question, so that we can provide an answer without having to answer multiple questions.

Comment: It needs to push 1 into the stack, then add 1 to the variable at the previous address then pop it again.

Comment: VS has tools that allows you to examine application memory while running in the debugger. What you're asking isn't really relevant to a VB developer as your app works the way it works regardless. If you want to understand these low-level details though, you should learn to use the tools that VS provides to access this low-level information. I haven't actually done so myself, as I've never had or felt the need.

Comment: @Jimi So if I understand you correctly, the  1 gets added to the previous address? No new memory gets allocated. If that is so, then what is the meaning of the statement "value type returns a copy when accessed"? What is the meaning of the term "accessed". So if I had written  Dim y as Integer = x, a copy of x is created in a new location. But when  I operate on x itself, no new memory space is being allocated. So does "access" mean assignment of a value type variable to a new variable  and not when we are operating on that same variable?

Comment: `Dim y as Integer = x`, passes the value of `x` to `y`, so a copy of the value assigned to `x`. Modifying `y`doesn't change `x` (since you just copied its value, there's no relation between `x` and `y`). When you do `x += 1`, you need to push `1` to the stack, `Add` it to the variable `x` at its address then pop `x` again. -- If you, instead of a Value Type, assign a Reference Type to another, you don't copy its value, you assign the reference of an object to another, which are now *linked* to the same structure in memory, so changing one also *changes* the other.

Comment: @jmcilhinney hi...i differ with you when you say that these low level details are not important. IMHO some of them are. For example unless someone understands the value types in full detail, he cannot understand why we are not able to set the height/width property through the SIZE property of the FORM class through direct assignment. Of course one can move ahead by accepting some thumb rules but then is it not better to understand the reason behind something?

Comment: @Jimi hi. thanks for your detailed comment. but what do you mean when you write "pop x again"? What does "pop" mean here - does it mean the old value of x being replaced by the new value at the same memory location?

Comment: *"unless someone understands the value types in full detail"*. I'm going to have to disagree. What exactly is "full" detail? It seems rather arbitrary to me. As far as you're example is concerned, all you have to know is that getting a value gets a copy, so setting a property on a value type you get from a field or property won't affect the original object. Why that's the case may be of interest but it's not required knowledge. As for your question here, what difference will it make to you if the answer is one way or the other? It won't change a thing. Interesting but irrelevant.

Comment: Push / Pop are standard terms used in relation to the Stack, to define the action of adding and retrieving elements from the *virtual collection*. -- You could explore this matter a bit and post your findings. -- In relation to the example you posted, when you get `f.Size`, you need to create a copy of the `Size` value (pop/push). Then you try to change one of the members of the structure, (push the new value, pop the struct, `add`, pop it again to reflect the new value. The Form class is totally unaware of this, because you're working with a copy of its `Size` value and its internal elements.

Comment: @Jimi we are allowed to write `Console.WriteLine(form1.Size.Height)`. Does that mean the height that gets printed is that of a duplicate (but same sized form)?

Comment: You read the Form class' `Size` struct. To read it, you need to extract its value. So, create a copy of the `Size` struct. `Height` is a member of the `Size` struct that you have copied. Setting `[Form].Size.Height` is then an irrelevant assignment, since it won't affect the `[Form].Size` value, just the copy you have pushed. Hence the warning, which translates to a *nope, can't do* error (since you still have a `[Form]` object on the left-most side of the assignment) (I'm stopping here :).

Comment: @jimi ...I like "I am stopping here"..:)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like some of the confusion here relates to the concept of "value type."

You consider the case of `Dim x As Integer = 10`.  Let's consider the case of the value `10`.  Let's suppose I also have another line, `Dim y As Integer = 10`.  We might ask about the location of the respective `10`s.  But I would submit that it actually doesn't matter: if I ask to compare `x` and `y`, I hope you would agree with me that they are equal, and we haven't considered whether one `10` is different from another `10`.

This, then, is the fundamental property of a value type: *identity is not a relevant consideration to a value*.  I might have one, two, or ten instances of `10`; all are considered to be interchangeable, and there isn't any fundamental difference that we can observe as to how the compiler happens to arrange them (into one, two, or ten instances).(*1)

If we try to extend the analogy to modifying one of the instances, I also hope you would agree with me that this is nonsensical.  It's hard to even formulate an example.  *This is why I argue very strongly that whenever you work with value types in .NET, the members should be immutable.  It's very hard to reason about mutable value types, because the idea of mutating a value is contradictory to the fundamental idea of what a "value" is.

To address your more specific question about `f.size`, I'd argue that there is  a fundamental authorship issue here.  Form size isn't something that really makes sense to me to be a unified value, because (as in your example) it might very well be reasonable to want to vary different aspects of the size independently.  The nature of a value type is that all of the members are connected, so that it wouldn't make sense to vary one independently from the others.

To address your very specific question about in what circumstances there is a copy, to my understanding, .NET will make a copy of a value type whenever it is modified.  So you won't necessarily be getting a copy back from `f.size`, but you will get a copy as soon as you try to change it.

(*1) In theory, this is the case.  In practice... you may occasionally hear grizzled veterans tell tales of woe.  This is mine: In a mid-90's Fortran compiler, constants from source code (like "0" or "0.0") were stored in memory to be loaded into variable at runtime.  I guess this was at least marginally more efficient than loading a literal "0" or "0.0" into the variable.  The compiler left the memory read-write.  Fortran uses pass-by-reference and separate compilation, so when a routine is called from a different file than where it is defined, it doesn't necessarily catch mistakes.  I had a fun bug where a constant 0.0 was used as an argument on the calling side, and the parameter was modified on the function side.  Much hilarity ensued when the value of "0.0" was no longer zero later in execution.  Subsequent versions of that vendor's compiler put the constants in a segment flagged as read-only, so the same mistake would have led to a hard crash (an access violation) instead of very mysterious misbehavior.